# css background- not fitting in a div

Tags: css

I have a div of fixed width and height as follows:

```
<div class="fontTest">A</div>
```

and I made a jpeg background image of size 800px*169px to fit into this div. Below is the css that I'm using:

```
.fontTest {
    font-family:'Noto Serif', serif; color:#744801; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    width:800px; 
    height:169px; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    background: #FDEEEE url('img/bkg1.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat fixed; 
}
```

I am using the shorthand background css property to define all the background properties in 1 line. Since the width and height of the images matches the width and height of the div- the image should perfectly cover the div- but this is not happening. The background image is only partly covering the div ([image: shown in the attached image]). Please help.

Comment: Try `background-size: cover;`

Comment: In your case, it seems the dimensions of the image are different from the container. So, there is a space. try to compromise the dimensions of the container or image. Or use `background-repeat: repeat-x`  to repeat the background horizontally.

Comment: #fiddle would be nice...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/probosckie/cmx661e1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the background attachment statement `fixed` in your shorthand property declaration.

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/ym2zL6j2/2/)

Re-size the view of the fiddle to see the difference.

> This keyword means that the background is fixed with regard to the viewport. Even if an element has a scrolling mechanism, a ‘fixed’ background doesn't move with the element.

```
.fontTest {
    font-family:'Noto Serif', serif;
    color:#744801;
    margin-left:auto;
    width:800px;
    height:169px;
    margin-right:auto;
    background: #FDEEEE url('http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-800-169-4.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This totally works. thanks. I was really wondering the whole time the problem was with the background position property (0, 0).
Here is a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/probosckie/cmx661e1/

Gotta read a little bit more about background attachment.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
background-size: cover;
```

and the image will cover the whole div.